# How to maintain order of key/value pairs in dictionary of python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a module in which a dictionary is used. This dictionary contains some key/value pairs, whose **order must be preserved** when using in other modules. But whenever I iterate over dictionary and print the keys, the keys are not in the order in which they key/value pairs are inserted.

So my question is how should I **preserve** the order of key/value pair in a dictionary?

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Do you mean the order in which the items were added to the dictionary? In that case you can use `OrderedDict` from `collections`: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @SimeonVisser: Yes, exactly. I want to maintain the order in which items are inserted. Thanks for the link. I'll check it and revert back to you...

Comment: I see there is a package at PyPI that provides OrderedDict functionality for Python 2.4, 2.5, and 2.6: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict . You can give that a try.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: I've checked python 2.7 documentation, and I found that OrderedDict exist for python 2.7... Thanx for the help... :)

Answer (score -1):

We know that regular Python dictionaries iterate over  pairs in an arbitrary order, hence they do not preserve the insertion order of  pairs.
Python 2.7. introduced a new “OrderDict” class in the “collections” module and it provides the same interface like the general dictionaries but it traverse through keys and values in an ordered manner depending on when a key was first inserted.
Eg:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderDict([('Company-id':1),('Company-Name':'Intellipaat')])
d.items() # displays the output as: [('Company-id':1),('Company-Name':'Intellipaat')]
```